# How can I know where USB Storage Device is mounted?

Tags: c, linux, usb

I need to know where the device was mounted(path). I'm using the libusb to know when the device is plugged.
And I need to know how to umount the device in C.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours searching, I found a solution!
Using "libudev", "mntent.h" and "sys/mount.h".

Manual libudev
http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/

Tutorial libudev
http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

mntent.h
http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent

sys/mount.h
http://linux.die.net/man/2/umount2

Thanks!